# IDispatchMessageInspector::AfterReceiveRequest Name of call service

Tags: c#, wcf

I implemented `IDispatchMessageInspector` and in method `AfterReceiveRequest` I can receive name of method (action) that calling from client like this `request.Headers.Action`. Can I found name of service that where this method was implemented? For example I have service `Test` and two methods `Start` and `Stop` and request.Headers.Action for this method like this   request.Headers.Action "`http://bla.my.com/Start`" and "`http://bla.my.com/Start`" How Can I found name `Test` and possible this or impossible?

Comment: How do you "receive name of method (action) that calling from client like this `request.Headers.Action`"?  This always comes back null for me in `AfterReceiveRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found suggestion: `instanceContext.GetServiceInstance()`returns name of service where implemented invoked method.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `request.Headers.To`, because we received message from client **TO** web service and if we parse property **TO** we are going to know name of service. And `instanceContext.GetServiceInstance()` is created new instance of service and this incorrect behavior for return name of service.